# Harbor Not Clearing GC Automatically

Tags: docker, gitlab, harbor

I need a small help from everyone here.

I am new to the harbor .

I am currently using Version v2.1.1 of Harbor.

I am trying to run the GC on daily basis automatically using crontab.

I have set the cron job to run at every 2 pm but it is failing,

Also whenever I try to set it to default daily

It gives an error,

This is long time and it is not yet sorted, Hoping to find a solution here :slightly_smiling_face:
I have attached the images for the reference if I am bad at explaining the problem.

Thanks,

Sameer

[image: You can check the crontab desc]

[image: You can check the history , we need to run it manually]

[image: When using the default cron setting it is giving this error]

Comment: if you need to run it daily at 2pm, the right cron schedule is `0 14 * * *`.

Comment: also, it is not clear whether the cron execution failed or setting the schedule itself failed, please post the error as well.

Comment: As per the harbor , IT also counts the seconds 
Check the second image which shows the right usage of cron schedule for harbor.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia There is no error or anything which is seen, it just doesnt run on the desired time. not sure what is making it fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is oddly stupid, but that "internal server error" is an error from component that fetches logs for all sorts of background jobs (like gc).

In harbor you can configure log to be sent to stdout (default), database or files (or their combination)
Only db and files options support fetching logs.

Look for an option to enable additional loggers (for versions around 2.4 - 2.5 installed via helm chart ) it's "jobservice.jobLoggers"

Only after setting that you will be able to see real error message why gc failed (or succeeded)